# Why is line-height being ignored when using flex display without text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The style `line-height` is ignored by the browser when not having text in it while in `flex` display. `line-height` is still being ignored even when having other components, like `inputs` or `text areas`.

Why is the `line-height` being ignored?

See running demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4K6PSN?p=preview).

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="line-height: 200px; background: blue;  display: flex"><input value="expected large line-height - success." style="width: 250px"/>ALIK</h1>
    <h1 style="line-height: 200px; background: red;  display: flex"><input value="expected large line-height - FAILURE!!!" style="width: 250px"/></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: @DJDavid98, You're right. Putting `&nbsp;` instead of Alik makes the line the same size as the blue line without seeing any text. Sounds like a hack though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`line-height` describes the height of line boxes. Line boxes cannot exist directly within a flex container — all flex items are blockified and any bare text within a flex container lives in a line box within an anonymous flex item (see [section 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) of the spec). In your first example, `line-height` applies to the line box within that anonymous flex item, and the `input` is sized accordingly.

`input` and `textarea` elements are replaced elements, and in this case their intrinsic height is used instead as per [section 10.6.2 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) (remember that they are blockified due to being flex items). So, without any text in your second example, there is nothing for `line-height` to apply to, and it is therefore ignored.

Comment: This is so implicit :(

Answer (score -2):

**EDITED:** 
Actually your line height is not being ignored at all. Line height takes place when there are multiple lines of text. Here is the slightly modified version of the code you gave us.

```html
<h1 style="line-height: 200px; background: blue;  display: flex"><input value="expected large line-height - success." style="width: 250px"/>ALIK</h1>
<h1 style="line-height: 200px; background: red;  display: flex"><input value="expected large line-height - FAILURE!!!" style="width: 250px"/>Lorem Ipsum sit Amet<br />Lorem ipsum sit amet</h1>
```

Comment: "Line height takes place when there are multiple lines of text." ... also when there is a single line of text, as already demonstrated in the control example.